# Identify and remove specific hidden characters from text file

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a text file that contains several hidden characters. Using `cat -v` I am able to see that they include the following;

> ^M
>
> ^[[A

There are also `\n` characters at the end of the line. I would like to be able to display these as well somehow.

Then I would like to be able to selectively `cut` and `sed` these hidden characters. How would I go able accomplishing this?

I've tried `dos2unix` but that didn't help remove any of the `^M` characters. I've also tried `sed s/^M//g` wherein I pressed **ctrl+v m**.

---

#### Raw data

Output from `cat -v` on the raw data,
also available at: http://pastebin.com/Vk2i81JC

```
^MCopying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)^M^[[A^[[A^[[Arescued:         0 B,  errsize:       0 B,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:         0 B,   errors:       0,    average rate:        0 B/s
   opos:         0 B, run time:       1 s,  successful read:       1 s ago
^MFinished
```

#### Output wanted

Also available at: http://pastebin.com/wfDnrELm

```
rescued:         0 B,  errsize:       0 B,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:         0 B,   errors:       0,    average rate:        0 B/s
   opos:         0 B, run time:       1 s,  successful read:       1 s ago
Finished
```

Comment: sed ^M will failed if you only work line by line because it is part of the line separator. You need to load at least 2 line with a `N` (one of the method) before using your `s` command. In this case i certainly load all the file in the working buffer before starting the `s` once

Comment: The `^[[A` sequences are probably terminal control codes.  Removing them is complex; there can be varying numbers of characters after the initial `^[` (escape) character.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix?  Particularly with the control-M characters, it matters — on Windows, control-M is an important part of the line ending in normal text files (two characters, control-M or CR and control-J or LF mark the end of a line).  On Unix, the CR characters are far less important, not being required except by Internet standard protocols or Windows compatibility.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Linux. The text file was generated via a `ddrescue` logfile.

Comment: That makes life a whole lot easier!  You mention in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778587/?noredirect=1#comment40335524_25779386) that you want to remove text surrounded by `^M`.  Can you give more context?  Are these within a line, or do they span lines?  `sed` is line-based; `tr` is character-based; if you need cross-line matching, you probably need to move to Perl or Python.  With luck, you won't need to do that.

Comment: In another [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778587/identify-and-remove-specific-hidden-characters-from-text-file?noredirect=1#comment40337736_25779386) I link to examples. The `^M` surrounds "Copying non-tried blocks..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below `tr` command which is used to translate or delete characters. The below command removes all the characters other than the one specified in octal within the quotes

octal \12 - new line(\n),  octal \11 - TAB(^I), octal \40-\176 - are good characters.

For a complete reference of octal values refer to this page:
https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/ascii-code-table.html

```
tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176' < org.txt > new.txt
```

The file `new.txt` will contain the characters removed.

To remove the characters between ^M and remove the unnecessary control characters use the below command

```
sed "s/\r.*\r//g" org.txt | tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176' > new.txt
```

Comment: This worked fairly well. I can now remove parts of the file I don't want, but I would still like to be able to cut using `^M` as a delimiter. I have text surrounding two `^M` that would I like to remove as well.

Comment: Can you give an example file or sample input and expected output ?

Comment: I'm curious that you think `\11` (aka decimal 9, or control-I, or tab) is called 'form feed'; that is normally `\14` (aka decimal 12, control-L, or form feed).  I was going to write that I wouldn't choose to keep form feed and would choose to keep tab, but then realized that your code actually does keep tab.

Comment: Here is a snippet example generated via `cat -v`: http://pastebin.com/Vk2i81JC
And here is how it should look and how it appears via `cat`: http://pastebin.com/wfDnrELm

Comment: @Jonatha Leffler , Yes you are right \11 is tab , \14 is form feed,I will correct the answer and  thanks for pointing that

Comment: @p014k please try the command sed "s/\r.*\r//g" org.txt | tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176' > new.txt , the 1st sed command tries to remove the pattern ^Masbdad^M and then the tr command removes all the other unnecessary control characters

Comment: @pO14k I have updated the answer to work as per you requirements